# getView is never called for reasons beyond me

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a custom list view adapter populated through an asynctask, I'm calling notifydatasetchanged in the onprogress function, and getCount() returns 10, yet my list never shows, Ive set a breakpoint and determined that getView() simply never is called. any ideas? Ive tried for hours and Im just stumped. Ive done the exactly same thing in another activity except that one used viewholders, this one only holds text based data so I didn't bother.

Adapter:

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  if(row == null) {
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcastepisode, null);
  }
  PodcastItem item = items.get(position);
  TextView episodeTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.episodeTitle);
  TextView episodeDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.episodeDate);
  episodeTitle.setText(item.title);
  episodeDate.setText(API.FormatPodcastDate(item.date));
  return row;
}
```

My task:

```java
protected void onProgressUpdate(PodcastItem... progress) {
  AddPodcastActivity.episodes.add(progress[0]);
  AddPodcastActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend moving your list adapter from inside the Activity file to it's own file, and using something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class EpisodeArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public EpisodeArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        items = new ArrayList<PodcastItem>();
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<PodcastItem> items;

    public void add(PodcastItem item) {
        items.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        items.remove(index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        items.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return items.size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { return items.get(position); }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null) row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.podcastepisode, null);
        PodcastItem item = items.get(position);
        TextView episodeTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.episodeTitle);
        TextView episodeDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.episodeDate);
        episodeTitle.setText(item.title);
        episodeDate.setText(API.FormatPodcastDate(item.date));
        return row;
    }
}
```

This is the type of code we use for all the list adapters in Boid :) Also, notice that the add/remove/clear functions call notifyDataSetChanged(), which makes it so you don't have to call it yourself when adding items.

When you initialize it, you would just use:

```
EpisodeArrayAdapter adapter = new EpisodeArrayAdapter(this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adding items with the add() function will cause the list to update immediately. Make sure you call setAdapter for the list view that's using the adapter, otherwise there won't be any connection and nothing will show up in the list (didn't see a call to this in your code).

Comment: wow... I forgot the setadapter.. WOW. I feel stupid. oh well. But either way, I will put this less messy approach to use (: Thank you so much, Really appreciate it!

Comment: Haha I did the same when I first started out with the Android SDK ;) but yeah using the BaseAdapter makes it really easy, you're welcome!